# Problem with my dev tools in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I open any page of website and check in console in Dev tool in chrome browser it shows a lot of `child-div` values, i don't know why, I am attaching a screenshot check below

[image]

[image]

on clicking model.js it shows the same code for every website.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any extensions active in chrome? If so, have you disabled them to see if they're causing the problem?

Comment: no extensions I have deleted all, I have one colorpicker and ad blocker which I already uninstalled

Comment: So click on the modal.js file and see the line and the file

Comment: @epascarello I have updated my code with model.js

Comment: Can you check the network tab to see where `modal.js` is coming from? Does this happen in any other browser? Does this happen for all websites you visit, or just this one? Based on your screenshot, it doesn't look like `modal.js` is coming from realpython.com directly.

Comment: So this doesn't happen in Firefox at all, but does happen for every single site you visit in Chrome? How about in Chrome incognito mode?

Comment: it is not happening in Firefox, also as I have checked not happening in chrome incognito mode

Comment: I guess there is some  chrome dev tool setting which is showing every web page child and parent div @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: If it doesn't happen in Chrome's incognito mode then it still sounds like an extension issue. The dev tools aren't affected by incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the problem (i.e. which web page you're looking at, does it actually happen for every website you visit, etc) it could be challenging to know why this is happening but here are a couple ideas:

1. I'd say modal.js on the site you're looking at (or a site you have looked at - see below) is logging things related to children of some element to the console. If this is the case, you can clear the console log but, unless you control the site, you won't really be able to prevent it.
2. If this is showing up on *every* web page you visit, it may be the case that your logs aren't being cleared between different pages. You can check if this is the case by looking in your Dev tool settings to see if the "Preserve log upon navigation" setting is checked (see below for how to check this). If this option is selected, you should be able to deselect it and it may stop showing that on every page.

[image: Chrome DevTools settings]

[image: Preserve log upon navigation]

Comment: everything seems fine just like yours.I have updated with few more info